# Deprecation errors on GitLab CI when testing F3 request mock using PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, gitlab-ci, fat-free-framework

I'm attempting to setup unit testing with PHPUnit 9.5 on my GitLab repo. The codebase is PHP 7.3, and I'm using Fat-Free Framework v3.7. Because the web app uses sessions, setting up a test to call `$f3->mock()` results in an error about headers already being sent, which makes sense since the session info is communicated via HTTP headers. I'm not aware of a way to get around this without editing the F3 code itself, but if anyone knows of a way, then everything below can probably be ignored.

It seems a fairly common consensus online to run such tests with the `@runInSeparateProcess` flag, so I've tried adding that. However, now when the test runs in GitLab, I get the following error:

```
   │ PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Fatal error: ini_set(): Use of mbstring.internal_encoding is deprecated
   │ [Standard input code:93]
```

Just for debugging purposes, I added `php --ini` to my provisioning script for GitLab CI to find the PHP INI files, which gave me:

```
+ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini
```

So then I added `grep -r "mbstring.internal_encoding" /usr/local/etc/php/` and got:

```
+ grep -r mbstring.internal_encoding /usr/local/etc/php/
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production:;mbstring.internal_encoding =
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production:; mbstring.internal_encoding setting. Input chars are
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production:; given by corresponding encode setting. When empty mbstring.internal_encoding
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development:;mbstring.internal_encoding =
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development:; mbstring.internal_encoding setting. Input chars are
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development:; given by corresponding encode setting. When empty mbstring.internal_encoding
```

Unless I'm mistaken, all of those look like they're commented out, so now I have no idea where to go to override the use of `mbstring.internal_encoding`.

#### Applicable File Excerpts:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: php:7.4

before_script:
  - bash tests/docker_install.sh

test:app:
  script:
    - app/vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php --testdox --colors tests
```

`composer.json`:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "bcosca/fatfree": "^3.7",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1",
        "google/recaptcha": "^1.2",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.2",
        "google/cloud-iot": "^1.1",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.7",
        "google/cloud-secret-manager": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^9.2"
    }
}
```

`tests/docker_install.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# we need to install dependencies only for Docker
[[ ! -e /.dockerenv ]] && exit 0

set -xe

# install required stuff that doesn't come with the image
apt-get update -yqq > /dev/null
apt-get install git libonig-dev zip unzip libzip-dev -yqq > /dev/null

# install php # install php requirements
docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip > /dev/null

# setup and install composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

`tests/bootstrap.php`:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);

require __DIR__.'/../app/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__.'/../app/App.php';
require __DIR__.'/TestBase.php';

\App\App::instance()->testingBootstrap();
```

`tests/ExampleTest.php`:

```
<?php
class ExampleTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    /**
     * @runInSeparateProcess
     */
    public function testPingResponse() {
        $f3 = \Base::instance();
        $this->assertNull($f3->mock('GET /ping'));
        $this->assertStringContainsString('alive', $f3->RESPONSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: ini_set(): Use of mbstring.internal_encoding is deprecated` means that code call `ini_set()` at runtime to set the setting.